# Messenger on High Sierra crashes at start

Tags: applications, high-sierra, mac-appstore, crash

It has been around two months that Messenger, right at start, crashes with the following message:

[image]

It never worked really. I kept it installed and waited for various updates (I have the latest version, 96.0) but always the same behaviour. I tried to delete & reinstall, no luck.

Those are my details, serial hidden for privacy:

[image]

According to the App Store, High Sierra should be supported:

[image]

I also have it installed on a 2019 MacBook Air with Big Sur; needless to say, it works perfectly.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't test this as I don't use Messenger, but try navigating to `~/Library/Saved Application State/` then scroll down until you find messenger's folder - it may start `com.facebook.messenger…` Delete the messenger folder, then try the app again.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but there is no such folder there.